# In emacs's perspective mode is there a way to preserve multiple locations in a single buffer when switching perspectives?

Tags: emacs

I have been using perspective mode for some time, and on the whole it is excellent. However if you have a single buffer open in multiple windows and switch perspectives, when you change back each window shows the same location in the buffer. Is it possible to preserve the different locations when switching perspectives?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else is curious, using clone-indirect-buffer rather than simply splitting the frame seems to do exactly what I want.